replacing the eval function
Im making a Calculator project, I have made a function which gets the user input inside the input tag and A eval() function that will calculate it and prints it on output tab.
But I want to replace eval(), and want the same funcationality under the input tab.
-> here is my js code-


const userInput= document.getElementById('input');
const userOutput= document.getElementById('output');
const clearbtn= document.getElementById('clear');
const calBtn=document.getElementById('calcBtn')
//selecting all the input btns at all
const btns= document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');

function calc(){
    //looping through each btns
    btns.forEach(button =>{
        button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

            let btnDataType= button.dataset.type;
            if(btnDataType==='number'|| btnDataType==='operator'){
                //appending the value;
                userInput.value+= button.value;
            } 

        })
    })

    //it will clear the input display
    clearbtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        userInput.value='';
        userOutput.value='';
    })

    calBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        try{
            console.log("Input value:", userInput.value);
            userOutput.value= eval(userInput.value);
        }
        catch(e){
            userOutput.value='Invalid selection';
        }
        
    });
}
calc();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body >
    <!-- header section -->
   <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Logo</a>
            <button>contribute here</button>
        </nav>
   </header>

   <!-- main -->
    <main>
        <section>
            <!-- calculator wrapper div -->
            <div>
                <!-- input and output screens -->
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type to Calculate" id="input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Output" readonly id="output">
                    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
                </div>

                <!-- wrapper that contains number btns , operators -->
                 <div>

                    <!-- numbers -->
                    <div>
                        <input type="button" value="0" id="0"  data-type="number">
                        <input type="button" value="1" id="1" data-type="number">
                        <input type="button" value="2" id="2" data-type="number">
                        <input type="button" value="3" id="3" data-type="number">
                        <input type="button" value="4" id="4" data-type="number">
                        <input type="button" value="5" id="5" data-type="number"> 
                        <input type="button" value="6" id="6" data-type="number">
                        <input type="button" value="7" id="7" data-type="number">
                        <input type="button" value="8" id="8" data-type="number">
                        <input type="button" value="9" id="9" data-type="number">
                    </div>

                     <!-- operators btns -->

                    <div>
                        <input type="button" value="+" id="+" data-type="operator">
                        <input type="button" value="-" id="-" data-type="operator">
                        <input type="button" value="*" id="*" data-type="operator">
                        <input type="button" value="/" id="/" data-type="operator">
                        <input type="button" value="%" id="%" data-type="operator">
                        <button id="calcBtn">Calculate</button>
                    </div>

                 </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>





    
    
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>


strong text
i kinnda stuck in logic building , any suggestion will help me.

You don't say this, but I guess you want to remove the eval() function for security reasons? Why not check to see if the input only contains the characters 1234567890+-*/%? That would make your code secure. Otherwise you will have to actually parse the input and apply the operators programmatically yourself.

thanks, bt how can i make my custom parser

if you want a custom parser, you write it. Then when you're stuck after making a reasonable attempt, you ask what you're doing wrong
